# Where can I specify or change the Maven build lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

As far as I know,there are three lifecycles in Maven: Clean, Default Build, Site.

The weird thing is there is no configuration file specifying lifecycle the project uses,  the sequence of phases needed for a project. I can only find out a few plugins in the pom file.

I can understand something is probably defined by default? Maybe it is defined in the XML namespaces?:

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`

My question is:
What if I want to customize a lifecycle (such as change the order of phase or include one more phase) for my project? How can I do it in pom file? A phase can contain multiple goals. How can I specify the order of the goals in the phase when writing a pom file?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: This most important question which comes to my mind is: Why do you need to change the life cycle? For what purpose? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is not actually needed right now. But I just want to find out how the lifecycle is defined and what phases are there. As right now I can only view some of these phases in intellj maven project and not all phases of default lifecycle are there @khmarbaise

Comment: So if you don't need it why do you think about it? The question must have a background (some kind of problem?)... Technically the life cycle is defined (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-core/lifecycles.html). The phases are documented here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html What you see in IDEA is something different (the plugins bound to particular phases not really related)...

Comment: @khmarbaise what do you mean by:
the plugins bound to particular phases not really related

Comment: The plugins you are using are bound to life cycle phases which IDEA is showing... that's it... The phases which currently do not have any bindings are not shown...

Comment: @khmarbaise but check a empty project here without any plugins: https://prnt.sc/SqtSCuOCaXGn. The phases are same for all projects

Comment: First there a missing a lot of phases for example `generate-test-sources`, `pre-integration-test` just to mention a few... see the reference of the maven docs... That means IDEA is showing always the same which is not correct as well... apart from that `clean` as well as `site` are life cycles on their own...

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle is triggered by the chosen `<packaging>`.

You can write your own lifecycles.

But it is rarely useful.

Comment: Can you be more specific and add some code sample here? Appreciated